# Error establishing a database connection in godaddy.com

Tags: errors, server

I have a problem *Error establishing a database connection in godaddy.com*.I have worked my buyer website on localhost.

Now I want to upload on my buyer server on godady.com . I have tried lot of create new database and new password, but always time showing

> Error establishing a database connection

How can solved that problem

Comment: godaddy uses different servers for the DB than localhost. make sure you are using the right address

Comment: I have already make right address .But i cannot solve that

Comment: obviously you are not using the right address,password or DB name. ask help from godaddy support

Comment: I think that is better for me thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Did you change http://localhost to http://yoursite.com in your .sql file

Also ,check your client website database in phpmyadmin ,upload .sql file to it and also make sure your localhost databse have same prefix as your client  ,generally it is wp_ but if different change it .

connect to your client website through FTP and upload all files or only wp-content folder

It would fix the problem

Regards

Comment: if he can not connect to the DB, it doesn't matter much what is in the DB

Comment: he has to check  wp-config.php and confirm that it matches the mysql database name and password

Comment: I have already tried all option .But i can not solve the problem . I uploaded database godadady phpmyadmin . change prefix , change new database user name , database name password . I have already install new wordpress and import my database and upload only  wp-content folder .